# mongooseim cluster setup eacces error on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: erlang, xmpp, cluster-computing, ejabberd, mongoose-im

We are trying to create master-master cluster of two mongooseim instances on AWS in same virtual network..
All necessary ports are opened in AWS security group.

I suspect some issue with mongooseim setup on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

After running join_cluster command on one of the node we get error as follows ( refer screenshot )
**Error: {error,{badmatch,{error,eacces}}}**

Attached screenshot with details.
Server configuration was not changed except vm args as shown in attached screenshot.

is this an issue with your binary ? or some other glitch ?

[image][image]

Comment: have there been any developments on this? If you found a solution can you please share?

Comment: @SashaFonseca we eventually abandoned mongooseim and adopted ejabberd lasted version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself. Mongoose uses erlangs internal `mnesia` storage system for a lot of information including cluster topology. The default path for mnesia's storage is `/var/lib/mongooseim`. When you do a `mongooseimctl join_cluster ...` it needs to wipe it's mnesia store and basically pulls a copy from the cluster it's joining. The issue arises because it also tries to delete `/var/lib/mongooseim` itself, which it won't have permissions to do because the running user `mongooseim` won't have permissions of the parent directory, `/var/lib`. Nor should it.

The way I fixed this was by creating a subdirectory which it could safely delete and recreate and configuring it to use that as it's mnesia directory:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongooseim/mnesia
sudo chown mongooseim:mongooseim /var/lib/mongooseim/mnesia
```

Configuration for the mnesia directory exists by default in `/etc/mongooseim/app.config`. In mine it was the third line. Originally looked like this:

```
{mnesia, [{dir, "/var/lib/mongooseim"}]},
```

I changed the path to the new directory I created

```
{mnesia, [{dir, "/var/lib/mongooseim/mnesia"}]},
```

After that, I stopped and started mongoose and was successfully able to join the cluster

```
mongooseimctl stop
mongooseimctl start && mongooseimctl started
mongooseimctl join_cluster mongooseim@other.node.name
```